# Google oauth2 api client is not working properly

Tags: java, grails, client, authorization

I have some code in my grails 2.3.4's controller's action that uses google java client libraries to access the OAuth2 api. But when I create an instance of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow I get redirect_uri_mismatch error. The url google gives me is this `http://localhost:60720/Callback`, while I have defined the callback url in the google api console as this `http://localhost:8080/<myAppName>/<controllerName>/<actionName>`. When I copy paste my redirected url manually in the address bar replacing the one google gave me, my application works well.

I've registered the application as web application not installed application in api console. What can I do? Please help. If I couldn't solve this problem then I'll revert to the REST Api.

```
ResourceLocator grailsResourceLocator



JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.defaultInstance

File clientSecretsFile = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI("/configs/clientSecrets.json").file

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(clientSecretsFile)))

HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()

FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/oauth2_sample"))

List<String> SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build()

Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Okey I got the problem. LocalServerReceiver implements VerficiationCodeReceiver and its overrided method getRedirectedUri() returns the invalid address. It defaults to the host localhost and some empty port and the `/Callback` is hardcoded inside a `private static final CALLBACK_PATH` field. 


So I think I must look around to some alternative then the LocalServerReceiver class.

Answer (score 9):

Okey I've found the solution.

When you create `new LocalServerReceiver()` use instead `new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9089).build()`

I've chosen some empty port in this case 9089. Actually `LocalServerReceiver` is a http server that listens to google and google sends `code` param to this server. Now all you have to do is create a new entry in your Redirected URIs which is in this case as follows: `http://localhost:9089/Callback`. Note the port number is same as I've used in the code while building the server using `LocalServerReceiver.Builder()` class.

And voila!!! you got the access_token and refresh_token from the google.

Happy coding...  Happy Java clients...

Comment: Can you please tell me which library you used for importing LocalServerReceiver?

Comment: LocalServerReciever is marked final and there is no method to setPort.

Comment: how do you create a new entry in the Redirected URIs?

Comment: My maven fetches google-oauth-client-jetty-1.19.0.jar to resolve this import, for which this solution works fine. The redirectURI is set in the resources/client_secrets.JSON. This JSON you can download from your developers console.