# OAuth 2.0 with Google Calendar on Web Application

Tags: java, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm having problems with the URL callback for Google Calendar for a Java web application. I followed the docs successfully and got this working locally but I am now trying to run this on an EC2 instance.

The quickstart tutorial on [Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) says to select Application Type as 'other'. This worked fine for me locally.

However, when I try and run this on a server I am given the URL to follow in the logs and the URL has a callback with localhost over a different port every time. Since the app was no longer running on localhost, the callback was never received.

After some reading, I need to set the credentials to be 'web application' when actually running this on a web server. This states that I need to define a 'Authorised redirect URIs' and needs to have the correct port.

I was using the following, based on the tutorial for the redirect to the URL to authenticate the user:

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

[After reading this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002827/google-oauth2-api-client-is-not-working-properly) I then set the port in code so I could enter the same port in the credentials to then go into the client_secret.json (my app is currently running on 8080)

I am doing this via:

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build()).authorize("user");
```

However, this throws a bind exception since obviously the port is already in use.

Choosing a port I know is free (I tried 9999) does take me through to the page to allow me to authenticate which makes sense since the URI matches the one stated in the client_secret.json. This then throws a socket bind failure exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one
>   usage of each socket address ( protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.

A lot of examples I have seen online have not set the port, which then allows the AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp to pick a free port but how will this work when we need to specify the Authorised redirect URIs in the API Credentials?

Comment: Usually the error you get occurs when a process/program is using a port and another process tries to use the same, thus causing conflict. Because that specific port is already in use by a program, another program is prevented from using that same port. So make sure you use a free port. For your problem about OAuth, you can check this [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi) on how to use redirect URI. Also make sure that the redirect URI you use must be the same as the one you set up for your application in the Google API Console.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this. I actually had something else running on port 9999 which is why the above didn't work locally. The AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp builder has a setHost() method which works for the EC2 instance.

```
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(REDIRECT_URI).setPort(9999).build()).authorize("user");
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and I have a quite simple question, should setHost receive a name (example.com) or an IP (188.168.2.2)? With or without http://?